# Please explain this syntax of function signature in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been assigned to an ongoing ReactJs project. While reviewing code I came across a function definition whose signature looked like following:

```
handleInputs({ target: { name, value } }) {
```

handleInputs is a function that gets called on the onChange event of textfields. It's called as

```
onChange={this.handleInputs}
```

I tried to output the value of "target" in console but it threw an error. While the value of "name" and "value" is the name of the input control and the value in the control respectively.

Can someone please explain the function signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is object destructuring assignment syntax. We can pass the object to the function as argument where it will be unpacked based on the function argument (object keys) specified. In your case `this.handleInputs` this should be an object having the keys `target: { name, value }`. Inside the function we can directly access the key values. 
You can understand the syntax better with the following example from mozilla docs. Also see this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for more details

```
function whois({displayName, fullName: {firstName: name}}) {
  console.log(displayName + ' is ' + name);
}

var user = { 
  id: 42, 
  displayName: 'jdoe',
  fullName: { 
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe'
  }
};

console.log('userId: ' + userId(user)); // "userId: 42"
whois(user); // "jdoe is John"
```

Comment: It makes sense now as React does pass an event object to event handlers. So target corresponds to the target property of event object. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: One last doubt if you can resolve, why consoling "target" threw an error whereas consoling "name" and "value" did not?